# Can access the host via browser or cUrl but cannot ping

Tags: networking, dns, proxy

```
C:\>curl.exe http://google.com
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> ... </html>
C:\>ping google.com
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

Or by a simple java program:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: google.com
```

I'm behind an NTLM authentication proxy and using CNTLM access via localhost:3128. CNTLM is working fine.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the browser and curl both use the proxy, your client will send the HTTP request "as is" and DNS resolution will be performed by the proxy. When you ping, nothing will be sent to the proxy so your client is responsible for performing DNS resolution. It sounds like you are unable to perform DNS resolution from your client.

Perform a few basic nslookup commands from command line to see if that is the case.